# Call IdentityServer from FrontEnd app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, identityserver4

My project has a structure like:

1. AuthServer (Asp.Net Core Identity + IdentityServer4)
2. Api (Asp.Net Core)
3. FrontEnd (Angular 5)

How Can I login from Angular using AuthServer and username and password from AspNetUser table?

How AuthServer should generate token and return it to the Angular app?

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) library. [Here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html) is some official documentation.

Of course there are a lot more oidc js clients, but this one is more like an official one.

Comment: So basically, I can't call POST (with credentials) from my Angular to AuthServer which return token without OIDC client?

Comment: May be in theory you will be able to construct some calls (to the token endpoint, to the authorize endpoint etc.), but why would you do that?

Comment: I think the angular should go to the AuthServer, login and return to the website? Is it not a good path?

Comment: Well basically this is what happens. The Angular will be registered as identity server client. It will call it, authenticate on the login screen, and receive tokens from IdS. I'm just saying that you should use one of oidc libraries. Most of them have npm packages and typings, so you can easily use them in angular.

Comment: Okay, I see. What about login screen is the same as an AuthServer or Angular app should implement their own?

Comment: Its part of IdentityServer